# Oracle query with one extra custom conditional column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with customer data where the table contains customer name, id, age.
Now I want to write a query where the result contains all customer data(*) and one extra column age group.
Where the age group is 0-14, 14-25 and 25-50 but this data is nowhere in DB.
I need to write a condition on select * from the CUSTOMER query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `table_name.*` (or give the table an alias and use `alias.*`) to get all the columns (or you could list all the columns in the select clause) and then use a `CASE` statement to generate the `age_group` column:

```sql
SELECT customer.*,
       CASE
       WHEN age <= 14 THEN '0-14'
       WHEN age <= 25 THEN '15-25'
       WHEN age <= 50 THEN '26-50'
       ELSE '51+'
       END as age_group
FROM   customer
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can use CASE WHEN.

It should look like this, there are plenty of resources online if you want to go deeper into it.

```
select customer_name, id, age, 
(case 
when (age between 0 and 14) then '0-14'
when (age between 15 and 25) then '15-25'
when (age between 26 and 50) then '26-50'
end) as age_group
from tableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to create a [virtual column](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_editions.htm#ADFNS1328) to obscure the `CASE` expression:

```
ALTER TABLE customer ADD age_group as 
  (CASE
   WHEN age <= 14 THEN '0-14'
   WHEN age >= 15 and age <= 25 THEN '15-25'
   WHEN age >= 26 and age <= 50 THEN '26-50'
   ELSE '51+'
   END
  );
```

Then you can simply:

```
SELECT * FROM customer;
```